# Script to search directories for .deb files and copy them for another location

Tags: scripts

If i have a directory A that contain directories B , C , D  I need a script that search

Directories B , C , D for .deb files and if found copy them to a location i choose .

This script should reduce effort of hand search and copy .

Any idea ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you don't need to search recursively, then a simple bash brace expansion

```
cp -t /location/you/choose/ /path/to/A/{B,C,D}/*.deb
```

should work. If you want to search *all* subdirectories of A recursively, then the most portable way would probably be

```
find /path/to/A -name '*.deb' -exec cp -t /location/you/choose/ {} +
```

If your shell supports it, you could also use the `globstar` shell option to make `cp` recursive without using `find` - type `shopt` or `help shopt` at the shell prompt for more information. If you need to exclude certain subdirectories then you could add a `-prune` to the find command.

As always you need to think ahead about what you want to do in case of non-unique filenames - you could add a `-n` or `--no-clobber` to the `cp` command, or use the `--backup=numbered` option. In the case of deb files it probably doesn't matter, since (barring file corruption) any non-unique filenames should correspond to exact duplicate files.

Answer (score 4):

Doesn't look like you've tried anything, but anyway. Here's the line, `man find` will do the talking if you're actually interested.

```
find /path/to/A -name "*.deb" -exec mv {} /path/to/new_directory \; # Moves
find /path/to/A -name "*.deb" -exec cp {} /path/to/new_directory \; # Copies
```

Will move .deb files from A (recursive search) to new_directory. By the way, this is more *nix-related than Ubuntu-specific.

Comment: cp is what i want , move will cut & paste ty also man

Comment: All it takes is a little change... Use `cp` instead of `mv`... Anyway.